# Tagging schema for AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine, tags, schema, nosql, rdbms

Hey,
I'm using AppEngine for an application that I'm writing. So I need to assign tags each object. I wanted to know what is the best way of doing this. 
Should I create a space seperated string of tags and then query something like %search_tag% (I'm not sure if you can do that in JDOQL)?

What other options do I have ?
Should I create another class which will map every object to a tag?

Which would be the best from the point of view of scalability, performance and ease of use?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, '%search_tag%' type 'LIKE' queries do not work on App Engine's datastore.  The best you can do is a prefix search.

It is difficult to answer very general questions like this.  The best solution will depend on several factors, how many tags do you expect per entity?  Is there a limit to the number of tags?  How will you use the tags?  For searching?  For display only?  The answers to all these questions impact how you should design your models.

One general solution for tagging is to use a multi-valued property, such as a list of tags.
  http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/dataclasses.html#Collections

Be aware, if you will have many tags on your entities it will add overhead at write time, since the indexes writes need time too.  Also, you should try to avoid using multi-valued properties multiple times (or multiple multi-value properties) in queries with inequalities or orders.  That can lead to 'exploding indexes,' since one index row gets written for every combination of the indexed fields.

Comment: The number of writes will be negligible compared to the number of reads. Also I intend to define relationships between tags, such as a thesaurus. E.g. programming and coding should be clubbed together. That's a different story, since the number of tags is much smaller.
Thanks for the link